# Delphi - does Intellisense pick up record helpers?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I ended up using record helpers as a workaround to the fact that Delphi does not allow forward declarations of record types.

At least it compiles, but am rather unhappy with the fact that Intellisense does not pickup these helper methods:

```
Extents.TransformBy(Matrix);
```

TransformBy is a helper method. The code above compiles just fine, however TransformBy does not show up in the Intellisense List at all. I restart the IDE just in case, but still no luck. Am using Delphi XE 2.

I found the following statement regarding class helpers:

> Really a class helper is a compiler trick, behind the scenes it is
>   just functions operating on the class, but it doesn’t polute the name
>   space, and **works with intellisense**.

http://blogs.conceptfirst.com/blog/2006/05/08/class-helpers-good-or-bad/

So I still have some hope that this might eventually work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XE2, methods declared in record helpers do not show up in the list of available methods that appears when you type `.` and/or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>. It seems, according to my experiments, that XE5 resolves the issue and XE5 Intellisense can see helper methods.

If only Embarcadero would allow forward declarations of records so that we would not need to resort to record helpers to make our types behave.

Comment: Microsoft has way to let developers vote on which are the most pressing issues with their developments tools. They normally do a very good job of addressing the most popular issues. Is there something similar for Delphi/Embarcadero? How can we put some pressure on them to resolve this?

Comment: You can submit a QC report and try to garner votes for it. There may very well already be a QC report for this. In my experience, Embarcadero is not particularly pro-active when it comes to addressing issues on QC.

Comment: There is indeed a ticket which was closed in 2012:
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=8007
However when I saw that the top most voted feature 'Undo/Redo in VCL Form designer' created in 2002 was still open I decided not to waste my time :-) My oh my...

Comment: Probably someone tried to implement DFM Undo/Redo, and failed, and the feature was dropped. That's the usual reason why something a lot of customers request still isn't implemented 11 years later.  I have tried to implement features my customers ask for, and failed to do so as well. My DFM Undo feature is called "Revert" in version control. What I want is functional Code Insight and Error Insight.